# Xcode Server impossible to start

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server, xcode-server

I am having hard time with this Xcode server, already wasting days on that... I'm in Yosemite everything up to date. Everything was working good last week except that every time I had to reboot my mac mini server, I had to log in through VNC to start again Xcode server and I had all the time to go through painful process of choosing Xcode.app.

This stopped working, when I am choosing the Xcode.app, I got an infinite waiting time and and when hitting cancel he told me to agree user licence of Xcode...

I found command line to restart the server and got that result :

```
polarios:~ nicky$ sudo xcrun xcscontrol --restart
2015-02-02 16:34:46.006 xcscontrol[3197:22247] I am xcscontrol (version 2.0 from /Applications/Xcode.app)
2015-02-02 16:34:46.006 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Arguments: (
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcscontrol",
    "--restart"
)
2015-02-02 16:34:46.264 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Xcode version: 6.1.1 (6A2008a) (OS X SDK 13F26, iOS SDK 12B411)
2015-02-02 16:34:46.267 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Server version: 4.0.3 (14S350)
2015-02-02 16:34:46.267 xcscontrol[3197:22247] OS X version: 10.10.1 (14B25)
2015-02-02 16:34:46.269 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcsd.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:46.341 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcscouch.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:46.411 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcsredis.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:46.479 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcscontrol.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:46.560 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcscouch.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:47.876 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcsredis.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:47.950 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcsd.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:48.019 xcscontrol[3197:22247] Launching task: /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcscontrol.plist
2015-02-02 16:34:48.414 xcscontrol[3197:22250] [XCSHTTPResponse] Received an unexpected error: -1004 (Could not connect to the server.) - GET https://127.0.0.1:20344/api/ping
2015-02-02 16:34:50.785 xcscontrol[3197:22250] [XCSHTTPResponse] Received an unexpected error: -1004 (Could not connect to the server.) - GET https://127.0.0.1:20344/api/ping
2015-02-02 16:34:52.773 xcscontrol[3197:22259] [XCSHTTPResponse] Received an unexpected error: -1004 (Could not connect to the server.) - GET https://127.0.0.1:20344/api/ping
2015-02-02 16:34:54.632 xcscontrol[3197:22250] [XCSHTTPResponse] Received an unexpected error: -1004 (Could not connect to the server.) - GET https://127.0.0.1:20344/api/ping
```

I had this issue on Maverick with server app 3.2, I could not resolve unless it, I updated to Yosemite for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem after hours of search. I dig up deeply in the log of console. A bit before Xcode server issue I found some mention of an error about QuickLook. The error was saying that QuickLook cannot start because of missing /tmp. I looked and realise that symbolic link /tmp was pointing to /private/tmp which didn't exist. I then created that directory and give 777 permissions. And Everything worked again!

I think that was connected with MySQL installation that was messing around with me last week trying to open up a socket at /tmp/mysql.sock.

For people which have similar issue, my advice is to look deeply in the Server logs, search for xcscontrol, and look before what kind of error happened.

Comment: Good find ! Save my day